# How to Populate the dropdown in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to create one dropdown with some Data. Here is my snippet

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-ng-app="myApp"></div>
        <div data-ng-controller="programController"></div>
             Program:
        <select name="" id="program" data-ng-options="program for program in programs">
            <option value="">SelectProgram</option>
        </select>
            <script>
                var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
                myApp.controller("programController", function ($scope) {
                    $scope.programs = ['.NET', 'Java', 'Angular JS,'PHP','C++'];
                });
                 </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

But I get an empty dropdown. Is there any mistake in my snippet?

Comment: you forget the single quote in array  `$scope.programs = ['.NET', 'Java', 'Angular JS','PHP','C++'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the tested code and working for me.You wrote controller out side **data-ng-app="myApp"**.
And please insert single quotation in line
      '.NET', 'Java', 'Angular JS','PHP','C++' after third item

```
<div data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="programController">
        Program:
    <select data-ng-model="selectedItem" data-ng-options="program for program in programs">
        <option value="">SelectProgram</option>
    </select>
</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('programController', function ($scope) {
   $scope.programs = [
       '.NET', 'Java', 'Angular JS','PHP','C++'
    ];
});
</script>
```

Hope this will work for too.

Comment: @i Dont Know have you try it ?

Answer (score 0):

you forget single quote in array
`$scope.programs = ['.NET', 'Java', 'Angular JS','PHP','C++'];`

`ng-model` is not write in your code.
Try This

```
    <div data-ng-app="myApp">
    <div data-ng-controller="programController">
         Program:
    <select name="" id="program" data-ng-options="program for program in programs" ng-model="programName" >
        <option value="">SelectProgram</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

```
<script>
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
myApp.controller("programController", function ($scope) {
$scope.programs = ['.NET', 'Java', 'Angular JS','PHP','C++'];
            });
</script>
```

For more info https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

[Plunker link your code](http://plnkr.co/edit/yfcCTnutI24rMpGulW4A?p=preview)

Comment: hi Vipin Jain..Thanks for ur Response..i tried ur code..but this one also not  worked

Comment: can you see link provided above

Comment: yes...i use only  <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script> ..is there any  Scruipt file are required?

Comment: i have edited my answer with plunker code you can use this

Answer (score 0):

ng-options requires a ng-model too.

Check out the documentation : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions#!

And I am assuming that the list is typed in correctly